# Collect specific User Data (File, Files or Folder) in a 2013 Workflow

Tags: workflow, workflow2013

Here are my contraints:

I need to use a SP 2013 Workflow
I need to ask the user to attach a single File, multiple Files or a Folder to said Workflow

I already notice the CDFU Action is gone in SP 2013. How do I query the user for data?

Answer (score 0):

The answer (in my case, needing references to ListItems) is just using a SP 2010 Workflow and Workflow-Interop